# Connection With API always results in a CORS Pre-Flight Error

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, cors, preflight

Here is a *very* simple attempt I have to establish a connection to a certain API in order to eventually request certain data. The API requires that a token be passed with an Authorization header, as I have tried to implement with my, admittedly, very limited knowledge of JavaScript. However, no matter what I seem to change about this code or the research I do, nothing seems to circumvent a very particular error I get which is, in full : "Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status." The code I provide below is essentially the simplest version of the code I have, since almost everything else I implemented in order to solve this issue has made very little change to the errors I receive.

I have read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) that, if this request error is a result of an Authorization header, nothing can be done with direct server access, which slightly worries me. Also, if it helps, this is a link to the documentation of the [API](https://ballchasing.com/doc/api) I'm using. I would really appreciate some help with trying to circumvent this issue. Thanks in advance for anyone that helps!

```
<SCRIPT language = "JavaScript">
       var token = "ngtNLSLUFJV3bHkMXasoSxJlWmP8QmWlbPI4O5ab"
       
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

        request.open("GET", "https://ballchasing.com/api/", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
        request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        request.send();

       
   </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: You cannot circumvent the problem from browser JavaScript. You need a server-side proxy on a server under your control.

Answer (score 0):

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is a response header, so you can't assign it at client-side.

you can either change the server response header, or just use a proxy in development